# Norm of Hessian bound

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, gradient-descent

In *Algorithms for Convex Optimization* by Vishnoi, problem 6.2 states

> Prove that if $f$ is twice-differentiable and has a continuous Hessian, then $\nabla^2 f(x)\preccurlyeq LI$ is equivalent to the inequality
> $$f(y)\leq f(x) + \langle y-x,\nabla f(x)\rangle + \frac{L}{2}\lVert x-y\rVert^2.$$

**My Work**: Now, I have seen this explanation on this site and in Vandenberghe's slides **with** the imposition that $f$ is convex, but here we do not assume that. I then assume this is a typo as I haven't been able to get this to work. The direction ($\Rightarrow$) holds without the condition if we take the Taylor expansion of $f(y)$ and use Cauchy-Schwartz. But the reverse direction, $(\Leftarrow)$, doesn't seem to work for me - I considered MVT, FTC, and Taylor expansion as candidate tactics, but I have trouble ensuring the inequality doesn't flip.

**My Question**: Is ($\Leftarrow$) possible without convexity, and if not, are there some simple counterexamples? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(t) = f(x+t(y-x))$. Then $g'(t) = \langle y-x, \nabla f(x+t(y-x))\rangle$, and $g''(t) = \langle y-x, (\nabla^2 f(x+t(y-x))) (y-x)\rangle$.

By Taylor's theorem, $$g(1) = g(0) + g'(0) + \frac{1}{2} g''(\xi_y)$$ for some $\xi_y \in [0,1]$.

The inequality in your original problem implies $$g(1) \le g(0) + g'(0) + \frac{L}{2} \|x-y\|^2.$$

Thus $g''(\xi_y) \le L\|x-y\|^2$, that is,
$$\left\langle \frac{y-x}{\|y-x\|}, (\nabla^2 f(x+\xi_y(y-x))) \frac{y-x}{\|y-x\|}\right\rangle \le L.$$

If we take $y \to x$, then this converges to $$\langle u, \nabla^2 f(x) u\rangle \le L,$$ by the continuity of the Hessian, and where $u$ is the unit vector $(y-x)/\|y-x\|$. Since $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary, this inequality holds for all unit vectors $u$.